# How to inject service into Symfony 2 Data Fixtures?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I inject a service into [Symfony2/Doctrine2 Data Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)? I want to create dummy users and need the `security.encoder_factory` service to encode my passwords.

I tried defining my Data Fixture as a service

```
myapp.loadDataFixture:
    class: myapp\SomeBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadDataFixtures
    arguments:
        - '@security.encoder_factory'
```

Then in my Data Fixture

```
class LoadDataFixtures implements FixtureInterface {

    protected $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct($encoderFactory) {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $encoderFactory->getEncoder(new User());
    }

    public function load($em) {
```

But got something like

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   ...\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadDataFixtures::__construct(), called in ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [Using the Container in the Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures) section describes exactly what you need.

All you need to do is to implement the `ContainerAwareInterface` in your fixture. This will cause the Symfony to inject the container via Setter-Injection. An example entity would look like this:

```
class LoadDataFixtures implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {

     /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load($em) {
```

You **don't** need to register the fixture as a service. Make sure to import the used classes via `use`.

Comment: This does not look like a SOLID sollution to the question

Answer (score 4):

For DoctrineFixturesBundle v. 3, you don't need to inject the container to inject a simple service. You can use normal dependency injection instead:

```
// src/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

// ...
private $encoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}
```

However if you do need the container, you can access it via the $this->container property.

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures).

Comment: I'd love to see this working but it don't. With DoctrineFixtureBundle 3.1 I can't inject services into my Fixture, I get : Too few arguments to function Kernel\DataFixtures\MongoDB\UserFixture::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php on line 193 and exactly 1 expected.

Comment: Ok, found the issue, It doesn't works with Doctrine ODM right now : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/461

Comment: Definitely the best solution for modern Symfony versions ! (Works great on 4.4)